# Вычисление возраста

Tags: c#, sql

Есть данная таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно вычислить среднюю продолжительность жизни у женщин и мужчин.
Вывести в текстбокс.

Но есть проблема в составлении sql запроса..

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database777.mdb;";

conn.Open();
string my_querry = "SELECT AVG ([Дата рождения])  FROM [Новорожденные] where[Мужской]";
OleDbCommand cmd4 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);

count = (int)cmd4.ExecuteScalar();
AVG.Text = count.ToString();
conn.Close();
```

Avg текст бокс

UPD
Решил последовать по самому последнему посту,пока что не получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем проблема?

Comment: @Eugene Понятия не имею как в данном случае составить  запрос,нужно ведь еще производить вычисления

Comment: Вычитание дат, `AVG`  и `GROUP BY` вам в помощь

Comment: Че-то я не понял: таблицу показываете "Умершие", запрос к таблице "Новорожденные". Так где, в итоге, хранятся даты рождения и смерти? В одной таблице или разных? Приведите в вопросе структуру(!) таблиц, скрин с данными не информативен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не назвали базу, поэтому вот Вам запрос, который решает Вашу задачу для MS SQL:

```
SELECT [Пол], AVG(DATEDIFF(day,[Дата смерти],[Дата Рождения])) AS 'Duration' 

  FROM [Умершие]

  GROUP BY [Пол]
```

Соответственно для для каждого пола он выводит среднюю продолжительность в днях. Если Вам продолжительность нужна в других величинах, то это делается с помощью первого параметра функции `DATEDIFF`. Вот ссылка на ее описание https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/ms189794

P.S. Screen теста:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.P.S.: Добавляю по Ваше просьбе пример фрагмента кода для чтения данных:

```
OleDbDataReader dr;

dr=cmd5.ExecuteReader();

while( dr.Read )
{
    string gender = dr.GetString(0);        //род - колонка с номером 0
    int duration = dr.GetInt32(1);          //Продолжительность - колонка с номером 1
}
```

В Вашем случае этот цикл сработает дважды. Поскольку Вы не дали своего кода, то встраивать чтение данных Вам придется самому. Естественно, что это все должно быть в скобочках `try {} catch()`.

Еще одно замечание - номера полей, которые используются как аргументы в функции `dr.GetString(...)` и `dr.GetInt32(...)`, могут быть вычислены с помощью функции `dr.GetOrdinal("Пол");` и `dr.GetOrdinal("Duration");`

Полезные ссылки на тему `OleDbDataReader`:

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=netframework-4.7.2

https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.6.php

Comment: выдает Отсутствует значение для одного или нескольких требуемых параметров

Comment: Проверил Ms SQL - работает, как часы.

Comment: Проблема с выводом.  проблема скорее в этой строчке count4 = (int)cmd5.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: Не туда отправил свой комментарий - естественно, Вы для получения данных из базы используете ExequteScalar, а мой запрос возвращает DataSet, поэтому Вы получаете исключение.  Я был уверен, что у Вас в этом месте не возникнет проблем.

Comment: Извините я тупой,что мне использовать вместо ExecuteScalar()

Comment: Используйте ExecuteReader. В данном случае это самый простой вариант. Если сами не справитесь - завтра я дополню ответ. Сейчас извините не могу.

Comment: Вот так ? int haha=dr.GetOrdinal("Duration"); Avg.text=dr.GetValue(1).ToString();

Comment: Я заменил GetValue, которые возвращают Object специализированными функциями, дабы Вам не нужно было заморачиваться приведением. Соответственно Вы должны сами трансформировать цикл (он носит чисто иллюстративный характер), в которым читается результирующий DataSet из двух строк строк и двух колонок в значения своих переменных.

Answer (score 0):

Не самый лучший, но рабочий вариант. В параметр функции передаёшь значение пола, функция возвращает массив со всеми вычисленными значениями возраста определённого пола. А уже потом делишь сумму массива на количество элементов. В идеале, конечно, всё это делать сразу через функции SQL.

*upd:* убрал "обёртку" php, оставил шаблон sql-запроса

```
SELECT [Пол], [Дата рождения], [Дата смерти], 
(YEAR([Дата смерти])-YEAR([Дата рождения]))-(RIGHT([Дата смерти],5)
<RIGHT([Дата рождения],5)) AS [Возраст] FROM [Люди] 
WHERE [Пол] = '{входной параметр функции}'
```

Comment: В тегах вопроса c#, а не php. Удалите код относящийся к php, оставьте только сам sql-запрос. Вообще же, запрос у вас зависит от пола, да и вообще неидеален. Посмотрите альтернативный вариант в соседнем ответе: вам на заметку для прокачки своего опыта.

Comment: Автору, ведь, и нужно сделать выборку по полам, других условий у него нет. В соседнем варианте используется DateDiff, насколько я знаю, он некорректно считает возраст, а в остальном да, более грамотный вариант.

Comment: Прошу посмотреть последний скриншот.@azatt